How to automate this seemingly easy manufacturing process?
We are a physical bird repellent manufacturer and use stainless steel to manufacture these things:

We have a fully built out infrastructure that does everything from cutting the steel strip to pieces (for the base of the product), bend the steel coil (for the spikes) and the welding machine that attaches the strips to the base.
Short backstory: It is a very simple product, and a fairly simple but rather complex manufacturing process to automate as well. Have already automated some parts of it, and the biggest task would be automating the welding process. I'm a senior software developer in the web space so I have very strong programming experience, however I do not have any Arduino, hardware engineering or embedded software specific experience but of course some of this can be outsourced. Here's my plan and my questions:

Buy a robotic arm which will "pinch" the steel stripe from a box placed right next to the welding spot, and put it under the welding machine. The arm will also be fixed directly next to the welding spot, so it doesn't need to have an arm longer than 3ft.
Attach a camera right onto the head of arm. This will be navigated with a computer vision algorithm, probably trained with AI (probably a neural network). It will basically run the following loop:


is there a strip fitted in?

if yes, command arm no 1 go to input box and pick one spike out

command arm no 2 to lift strip (to make space available to fit in spike) -> call actuator to push stripe forward 4 inches (the distance between the spikes) -> fit in spike to welding spot -> lower strip back to original position -> move away -> call welding machine to weld -> repeat

if the last spike to be welded, lift completed product out of the frame and push it out and start again (operator will then put a stripe in manually)

Which robotic arm should I buy? I'm looking for one that requires minimal setup (like controllable from an Arduino?) to get going with. It will also also need to be durable and fairly precise. Is there one specialised for machine learning, that can be trained relatively easily? I believe AI will be an important piece of this, as sometimes the spikes can get stuck in a position which will need some "wiggling" to get out of.

What type of head should I buy for the arm? I imagine the input boxes to be always lined up with strips, so that they can be picked out easily. Would it be possible to take the strips out of the box even if they are not lined up perfectly but just randomly thrown in there? The strips are also quite thin in diameter (around 2-3mm - attached video below)


I took some images and videos of the situation (apparently imgur thinks this is porn, it isnt):
https://imgur.com/a/xaciPWx
As you can see it is a somewhat constrained setup (designed for manual use - old welding machine that doesnt allow for customization), and these limitations cannot be removed so need to work within these.
Appreciate any advice and insight

key piece of information: how many are to be built?

In the past this would have been done entirely mechanically (apart from the electric weld).



Station
Description




Strip unwind
Feed in a roll of strip on the left.


Strip flatten
Run it through some rollers to straighten it out.


Dimpler
Stamp the weld dimples on the strip.


Strip feed
Use a pinch feed system - either rollers or two pairs of grippers, one fixed and one moving, to index once per cycle. This will pull from the previous stations and push the strip through the rest of the operation.


Wire unwind
Feed in a roll of wire at 90°.


Wire feed
Index the wire to align the weld point.


Welder
Weld the wire to the dimples.


Wire cut
Cut the wire at the infeed end.


Bending station
Clamp the strip and bend the wires downward.


Cut and offload
Cross-cut the strip into finished lengths.



The whole machine could have been run with one motor and a few cams. No cameras. No robots. No PLC.
If you want to automate then I offer the following observations:

Use a PLC, not an Arduino. There are many small brick type with mini LCD and keypad that are very versatile. See Siemens LOGO!, Allen-Bradley, Mitsubishi, Omron, etc. These will be somewhat industrial-hardened for reliability and 24 V (industry standard). The Arduino will be neither - unless you go for something like Finder's OPTA 8A.
Use on-off sensors where you can rather than vision systems. They're much simpler.
Universal Robots have much of the lower end of the market sewn up. They're easy to program and are designed to operate as cobots (collaborative robots) which may ease the guarding requirements - but seek professional advice on this. Your local agent should have a demo unit you could borrow for a week.


Would have answered this - but it would have been a simpler version of Transistor's.  A robotic arm will make a simple process much more complicated.

I  would suggest an entirely different design for the product, as follows.
buy a wider strip of stainless, where the width equals at least ~twice the wire length of the existing design.
Punch/shear the strip so it turns into a series of thin strips (like flattened wires) attached at the center of the strip where the shear stops, to yield a double-sided "comb" structure.
Roll the strip into the desired vee shape.
Mechanically "fan" the individual strips out separately from each other using another set of roller dies.
Now you have a continuous process which does not require attaching wires to a central strip. its effectiveness will be set by how thin you can shear the comb "teeth".
